# Symfony 3 - Don't undertsand why my request value is null

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have checkboxes in my twig file depending on the users I want to delete. Then I have a button that refers to an action of the controller that is supposed to recover through the Request list of checked checkboxes. Only, each time, the list is null.

```
<th><a href="{{path('user_delete_masse')}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer plusieurs utilisateurs </a></th>

//...
{% for ....%}

<td><input type="checkbox" name="usersSuppr[]" value={{unUser.username}} /></td>
{% endfor %}
```

**controler :**

```
/**
     * Suppression de plusieurs utilisateurs en même temps
     * 
     * @Route("/delete/masse", name="user_delete_masse")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function deleteMasseAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump('delete masse');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager

        $listeUsernames=$request->get('usersSuppr');
        dump($listeUsernames);
//...
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve the element "usersSuppr []" without having to use a  ? Because I already use 2 in my twig file for other features and I can not add this feature with a  because it would be a problem, it would mix with others

Comment: You are using a link so the checkboxes are not submitted. Instead you should be using a form.

Comment: And knowing that I already have several forms that mix a little, is it possible to say that the input is for such form?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You can have multiple forms and check if they have been submitted with $form->isSubmitted().

Comment: Oh yes, I'm very stupid ... It works, thx !